# Save same file to SD Card with multiple names

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

This is the code for Writing file to SD card.

```
    try {
        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myFile = new File(file, "sample.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(Globals.obj.toString());
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Written successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Here 'sample.txt' is the file which is saved to SD card. Once the user enters `EditText` value and on click of `Button` it is saved to card. Another user comes and his contents are saved as'sample1.txt' and for another user it is saved as'sample2.txt','sample3.txt'(incremental order) and so on.. Can anyone tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME);
if(file.exists()){
 ...
}
```

OR

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "yourpath");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();
        // substr the name to find the last digits
}
```

You can check if the file exists and then append the corresponding number.

Comment: First you try with it. Then if for some reason you can't continue, let me know what you wrote and we'll think of something ;-)

Comment: I tried something like this http://pastebin.com/hAaZTyKm and in both files same texts are saved.

Comment: You want a different text in each file, because it corresponds to the input of different users - right? If so, then you'll need a different filename -right?

Comment: ya that's right..  it corresponds to the input of different users.

Comment: So, you have different files with different filenames I suppose. I don't know of the solution which you gave, several comments above, but it seems to me that the last "save" of the file override all the files? If that's the case, it's easily manageable.